# Mirroring multiple source databases to a single destination in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

How can we maintain multiple source databases data in a single destination server database   in SQL Server 2008? They all are at different networks, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are those source databases using the same schema and have only different data? If yes, Grant's answer is for you, if not..only a custom made project will do. You might look into SSIS for this option.

Answer (score 4):

Mirroring doesn't work like that. You can't bring multiple databases into a single database. You need to [look to Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx), specifically [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx) as a solution for this. It can be set up across domains and it's specifically designed to take multiple different databases and bring them back to a single location. Mirroring is for creating a copy, a mirror, of a database. If you have more than one database, you'll have to maintain more than one mirror.